Stable bundles over $\Bbb P^1$.
Is there a direct way to see that the only stable vector bundles over $\Bbb P^1$ are line bundles? I think that this can be shown using the Birkhoff–Grothendieck theorem, but it seems like an overkill here. If $E$ is a rank $r$  vector bundle over $\Bbb P^1$ and $F \subset E$ any subbundle, then the stability condition gives
$$
\mu(F) < \mu(E) \iff \frac{\int_{\Bbb P^1} c_1(F)}{\text{rank}(F)} < \frac{\int_{\Bbb P^1} c_1(E)}{\text{rank}(E)} \iff  \text{rank}(E)\int_{\Bbb P^1} c_1(F) < \text{rank}(F)\int_{\Bbb P^1} c_1(E).
$$
However, I can't find a direct way to argue from here that $\text{rank}(E) =r= 1$. What additional information do I need?

I think it should be $c_1(E)$ in the last integral.

Thank you, made the correction. Any thoughts on if this possible without the theorem? @red_trumpet

$[\Bbb P^1,BU]=\pi_2(BU)=\Bbb Z$ is generated by the Hopf  line bundle.

On the contrary I feel if there is some way to prove directly that the only stable bundles over $\mathbb{P}^1$ are line bundles, then we may be able to use it to prove Grothendieck-Birkhoff theorem. Here is an argument in the rank $2$ case. So using the fact that any stable bundle is a line bundle, we have to show there are no indecomposable rank $2$ bundles which is the content of Grothendieck-Birkhoff theorem in rank $2$ case. On the contrary suppose there exists a rank $2$ bundle, then we claim the following
claim 1: If at all there is a rank $2$ indecomposable bundle on $\mathbb{P}^1$, then it has to be stable.
Let $E$ be a rank $2$ indecomposable bundle, if $E$ is not stable, then we have a short exact sequence $$0 \rightarrow L \rightarrow E \rightarrow \tilde{L} \rightarrow 0$$ where $deg(L) \geq \frac{deg(E)}{2} \geq deg(\tilde{L})$. Now such a short exact sequence corresponds to an element in $H^1(\mathbb{P}^1,\tilde{L}^{-1}\otimes L)$. But since $deg(\tilde{L}^{-1}\otimes L) \geq 0$, we have $H^{1}(\mathbb{P}^1,\tilde{L}^{-1} \otimes L) = (0)$ and hence the short exact sequence splits, which is a contradiction to indecomposability of $E$.
Thus if there are no stable bundles of rank greater than $1$ on $\mathbb{P}^1$, then we see that any rank $2$ bundle on $\mathbb{P}^1$ will split.

I know that (this is what is called as Grothendieck-Birkhoff theorem).. but OP wants a proof without using this theorem ...

@Desperado, OP wants to prove there are no stable bundles other than line bundles without using Grothendieck-Birkhoff.. but I believe proving this statement is as powerfull as proving Grothendieck-Birkhoff.. as a demonstration, I prove that using the stamenet about stable bundles, one can deduce Grothendieck's theorem for rank $2$ bundles... hope this clears it...

my comment is that you answered the OP question, only if the bundle is indecomposable, which is never the case! In other words, you proved something starting from a false assumption (the bundle is indecomposable): "Ex falsum quodlibet".

@Desperado, cannot understand you... what i have proved is there are are no indecomposable rank $2$ bundles via contradiction...I have edited the higlighted claim to avoid the confusion I might have caused...

@Charvaka is completely right in their reasoning.
